# Using duplicate rows in cover.design in fields package in R

Tags: duplicates

How would I use duplicate rows of data in the cover.design() function in the fields package in R? If not, is there another package/function I could use?

I've tried using the unique() function, but then I lose some of the duplicate rows I want to keep.